# Can I merge test expectation with test data together?

Tags: automated-testing, browser-automation, data-driven

I am coding a test automation framework which uses data-driven approach. The whole project is to test an online shopping web page.

An Excel sheet was created to contain all test data as following:

```
TestName Date1     Date2     FirstName1 etc
End_To_End_test    xxx       xxx        xxx
```

What I want to achieve is to include interim test expectation in this spreadsheet as well. Is that an accepted approach?

Comment: Both responses so far have questions about what is "interim test expectation". Could you use this concept with a more widespread vocabulary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not really sure what you meant by Interim Test Expectation, did you mean Checkpoint?

Sure you can do it, you can do something like this:

```
TestName Date1     Date2     FirstName1 etc    Checkpoint1_Result
End_To_End_test    xxx       xxx        xxx    Pass/Fail
```

Whether it should be a pass or fail, depends on your test design.

- A checkpoint is an automated comparison that you can have within an automated test. When the test is run, the checkpoint compares the value stored in the test (i.e. the baseline value) with the actual value and reports success or failure depending on the comparison. A single checkpoint replaces a number of test steps or script statements that perform the same comparison.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

I've definitely seen people (and have done so myself), where the data file contains response codes, strings, final states, etc.  All depends how general of a solution you want, if you want to run positive/negative, etc.